# List all enums defined in a package recursively

Tags: java, reflection, enums

Was using `org.reflections` API to find that it doesn't work with `Enums`:

```
List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<>();
classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder()
.setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner())
.setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
.filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("my.package"))));

Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Enum.class); 

// Above line should've returned all enums recursively, doesn't work!
```

Any alternate ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't require so much ceremonial codes, just try the below snippet.

`Enums` extends `java.lang.Enum` while Object just `Java.lang`

Modified code to work properly should be:

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("newPackaes");

    Set<Class<? extends Enum>> allClasses =
            reflections.getSubTypesOf(Enum.class);
    System.out.println(allClasses);
```

Comment: replace **newPackaes** to your *actual package name*.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick...and I did change package-name :P